# How to use Multiple JPA repositories that uses different Databases?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two JPA repositories. One Repository contains Postgres queries and the other one contain Oracle queries. They share the same function declaration, only the @Query(...) content is different(specific to Database). It's like, Oracle DB is used in some environments, and Postgres is been used in other environments.

*Structure*:

```
public interface OracleQuery extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

   @Query("oracle query....")
   User getData();
}

public interface PostgresQuery extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

   @Query("postgres query....")
   User getData();
}
```

Now,

```
@Autowired
OracleQuery oracle;

@Autowired
PostgresQuery postgres;
```

Instead, my question is, Is it possible to create a Generic Type which will decide during the runtime which Repository to look into based on the configuration or the profile provided?

Something like,

```
@Autowired
GenericType<?> oracle_postgres; // Based on the profile/ application configs, figures out which Repository to look into
```

The question might sound stupid, but is it possible? Since I am new to Java programming and Spring Framework, I am getting to understand the topics.

Answer (score 0):

try using different spring profiles for your envs. Then you can use `@Profile` annotation like e.g.

```
@Component
@Profile("a & !b")
public class UsedInProfileAAndNotProfileB {}
```